# Double fields firebase confusion

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to save some data on a firebase realtime database and I keep getting a duplicated field

I tried to change the models but that didn't change anything

```
submitVideoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String locationName;
    locationName = mLocationSpinnerName;
            if(!locationInput.getText().toString().equals("")){
                locationName = locationInput.getText().toString();
            }

            LocationData tompkins = new LocationData(locationName, 30, 
 31);


            String userid = mFirebaseUser.getEmail().substring(0, 
mFirebaseUser.getEmail().indexOf("@"));
            String cleanUserId = userid.replaceAll("\\W", "");
            updateUserInfo(cleanUserId, mFirebaseUser.getEmail(), 
"nsaofdhiqo3", tompkins);
        }
    });

}

 private void updateUserInfo(String userId, String email, String videoId, 
 LocationData location) {
    VideoEntry videoEntry = new VideoEntry(videoId, location);
    UserData user = new UserData(email, videoEntry);

    mDatabaseRef.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
 }
```

VideoEntry.Java

```
   public class VideoEntry {
    public String text;
    public String mVideoId;
    public LocationData mLocationData;

    public VideoEntry() {}

    public VideoEntry(String text, String videoId) {
        this.text = text;
        mVideoId = videoId;
    }

    public VideoEntry(String videoId, LocationData locationData) {
        mVideoId = videoId;
        mLocationData = locationData;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getVideoId() {
        return mVideoId;
    }
}
```

UserData.Java

```
public class UserData {

    public String mName;
    public String mVideoId; //TO BE REMOVED
    public LocationData mLocationData;
    public ArrayList<VideoEntry> mVideoEntries;
    public VideoEntry mVideoEntry; //TO BE REMOVED

    public UserData(){}

    public UserData(String name){
        mName = name;
    }

    public UserData(String name, String videoId, LocationData locationData){
        mName = name;
        mVideoId = videoId;
        mLocationData = locationData;
    }
    public UserData(String name, String videoId, LocationData locationData, ArrayList<VideoEntry> videoEntries){
        mName = name;
        mVideoId = videoId;
        mLocationData = locationData;
        mVideoEntries = videoEntries;
    }

    public UserData(String name, VideoEntry videoEntry){
        mName = name;
        mVideoEntry = videoEntry;
    }

    public UserData(String name, VideoEntry videoEntry, LocationData locationData){
        mName = name;
        mVideoEntry = videoEntry;
        mLocationData = locationData;
    }

}
```

LocationData.java

```
public class LocationData {

    public String mName;
    public double mLongitude;
    public double mLatitude;

    public LocationData(){}

    public LocationData(String name, double longitude, double latitude) {
        mName = name;
        mLongitude = longitude;
        mLatitude = latitude;
    }
}
```

I am just trying to have **one** field instead of two videoIDs (mVideoId and videoID) I am thinking maybe is a java "gotcha" ? [image: Firebase Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase by default serializes/deserializes *public* fields, and "properties" (as identified by JavaBean standard getters and setters).

Marking your member fields as private should ensure they don't get written to the database:

```
private String mVideoId;
```

Alternatively you can mark a public field or getter/setter as `@Exclude`:

```
@Exclude public String mVideoId;
```

Comment: interesting but doesn't Firebase require the Pojo to have public variables or getter/setter ?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. A class with only public fields would work fine too. But the important thing is to have one or the other: or only a public field, or only a public getter/setter pair. Having both will result to both being written, and since your field name doesn't match the property name (`mVideoId` vs `videoId`) both are written.